# Snapchat API auth results in a ban

Tags: php, api

I am attempting to send snapchat's from the PHP API [here](https://github.com/JorgenPhi/php-snapchat).

As you can see it authenticates to the server a lot

```
<?php

// Log in:
$snapchat = new Snapchat('username', 'password');

// Upload a snap and send it to me for 8 seconds:
$id = $snapchat->upload(
Snapchat::MEDIA_IMAGE,
file_get_contents('/home/jorgen/whatever.jpg')
);
$snapchat->send($id, array('jorgenphi'), 8);
```

How is it possible to only authenticate once and then send the snapchat to an ARRAY of usernames?

Answer (score 0):

It appears you can send to multiple people by adding more elements to the array in 2nd parameter of the send function ([check here](https://github.com/JorgenPhi/php-snapchat/blob/master/src/snapchat.php#L883)).

Try something like:

```
$snapchat->send($id, array('jorgenphi', 'anotheruser', 'thirduser'), 8);
```

Comment: Hi Marcus, thank you for your reply. I understand that adding multiple usernames to the array will work. The problem I am facing is that each time the "snap" is sent to an array of users it first authenticates using $snapchat = new Snapchat('username', 'password'); which if you have an array of let's say 1000 users - it auths 1000 times (which in turn Snapchat bans/blocks that account).

Comment: From what I can tell looking at the classes, that doesn't appear to be true. The array of recipients is imploded, and passed to a single HTTP request. Is it possible you're being banned for sending to 1000 users instead of 1000 authentications?

Comment: Hmmm, possible. I have only tested with about ~50 users (and was blocked from sending after that). I was using 1000 as a reference to the question.

Comment: https://github.com/JorgenPhi/php-snapchat/blob/master/src/snapchat.php#L901 As you can see it is placed into a single string before being passed to https://github.com/JorgenPhi/php-snapchat/blob/master/src/snapchat_agent.php#L231

I don't think the issue is "spamming" the authentication

Comment: That makes sense - looks like I am back to square one.